# insert a related data in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have these two model class:

```
 public class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
    public class Comment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }
        public string CommentTxt { get; set; }
        public Article Article { get; set; }
    }
    public class ArticleDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

now I want to have a page that all comment that is inserted for an Article is listed and also at the below of list i can insert new comment for that article?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you don't yet know anything about controllers and views I recommend this free video series. indepth and well explained  http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: You need a **ViewModel** for that kind of stuff, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create viewmodel for this:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{ 
   public Article Article { get; set; }
   public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
   ArticleViewModel model = new ArticleViewModel();

   model.Article = _yourDBRepository.GetArticleById(id);
   model.Comments = _yourDBRepository.LoadCommentsByArticleId(id);
   return View(model);
}
```

In view you can add new comment item like this:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comment", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      @Html.Hidden("ArticleId", Model.Article.Id)
      @Html.TextBox("text", "", new { name = "text", id = "text", data_placeholder = "Enter comment" })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
//** Get Article
Public ActionResult Article (int ID)
{
Article article = db.Find(ID);
return(article)
}

//*Add comments
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Addcomment (int articleID, string CommentTxt)
{
  Article article = db.Find(ID);
  Comment comment = new Comment();
  db.Comments.Add(comment);
  comment.ArticleID = articleID;
  comment.CommentTxt = CommentTxt;
  db.SaveChanges;

  return PartialView(article);
}


//**Get List of comments after adding new comment
public ActionResult AllComments(int articleID)
{
  Article article = db.Find(ID);
  var comments = db.Comments.Where(a=>a.ArticleID == articleID).ToList();
  return PartialView(comments);
}
```

In Your Article View:

```
<sript>
$('.addComment')click(function(){
$post('/Home/Addcomment?articleID=@Model.ID&CommentTxt='+$('.commenttext').val()).always(function()
{
$('.comments).Load(/Home/AllComments/articleID=@Model.ID)
});
})
</script>

 //*Your article here
......

 //*Comments section
<div class="comments">@Html.RenderAction("AllComments", "Home")</div>

<input type="text" class="commenttext" />
<button class="addComment">Add comment</button>
```

In your AllComments View

```
<ul>
@foreach(var i in Model)
<li>
@i.CommentTxt 
</li>
</ul>
```